# BJCP Category for a APA with Rye and Wheat

Tags: bjcp, competition, pale

What would be a proper BJCP category to enter a Pale Ale with Rye and Wheat?  The wheat contribution is nearly 30% but the Rye is less than 10%.
It is crystal clear with a nice light rye bite.

It tastes like a great Pale Ale to me, but I would imagine it would be disqualified due to the rye content.

Alternate fermentable is an option too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it tastes like an APA, then it *is* an APA.  The judges don't get to see your recipe.  Always enter based on taste, not based on recipe.

Comment: That is what I was thinking.  Thanks for the feedback